# How to quickly butcher an animal without going all the way to the burcher shop?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

There's a Cow that somehow ended way down in my fortress and is starving. I know it would die before I could move it to a Pasture, so I'm looking for a way to kill it fast and butcher the corpse, since it would be a waste of meat, fat and leather. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Any sort of machinations to kill a cow that's far away would take at least as long as it would take a butcher to grab it and take it to a butcher shop. Why not just do that?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I have dwarves near enough to do the job (the miners dinner room/hang out is just beside it), while the butcher shop and pastures instead are very far away.

Comment: Then why not promote one of the miners to temporary butcher? Build a nearby butcher's workshop while you're at it. I'd wager a mangled corpse with an experienced butcher gives you less than a full corpse with an inexperienced one.

Comment: Actually, I believe Butcher skill only increases speed of butchering, not yield -- even more reason to simply field-promote a miner.

Comment: @RavenDreamer that's what I was thinking after asking the question. I'm going to check if there's a near room.

Comment: they are miners.... they _MAKE_ the room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if Mahoma don't go to the mountain, the mountain goes to Mahoma. So, I created a butcher shop near the Cow, assigning a near and available (aka, not sleeping or on break or a child) dwarf to only butchering and marked the Cow to be butchered. And, as every good DF story, the cow died nevertheless.

Comment: I tend to make and disassemble butcher shops on a regular basis, not only to locate them close to where the animal(s) to be butchered are, but also because the rotting byproducts of butchery like nervous tissue and cartilage tend to not be removed from the butcher's workshop for long periods of time (and often start producing miasma). Disassembling a workshop with stuff inside seems to encourage dwarves to move that stuff to stockpiles (or garbage piles) a little faster.